# Faster way to run Pagination Query in Snowflake

Tags: sql, pagination, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to snowflake, trying to implement paginated queries. For paginated response we need below two queries:

```
select * from snowflake_table where 'conditions' limit 10 offset 0;        // Fetching paginated rows
select count(1) as totalRecords from snowflake_table where 'conditions';   // Fetching total records count for same criteria
```

**Can we do this in a single query to make code faster or is there any better/faster way in Snowflake to achieve the same?**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get number of records satisfying the WHERE conditions using the same query:

```
select COUNT(*) OVER() AS totalRecords, * 
from snowflake_table 
where 'conditions' 
limit 10 offset 0;
```

Comment: Thanks.. This works, but it's too slow. executing above two queries separately or parallelly would be faster than this approach.